# Best way to deploy (J)Ruby application alongside multiple html5/gwt games built with Libgdx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gwt, libgdx, jruby, war

I have been learning about the libgdx framework, and I am completely in love with it. My associates and I have been developing several games over the last few months and are starting to think about deployment.

We've ironed out most of the wrinkles with our android and iOS builds. Now we are thinking about the gwt builds. I've built a small Ruby on Rails (MRI... for now) website where we'd like to host the GWT version of these games.

By default libgdx produces a .war package. I've done some research and it seems totally possible and normal to deploy multiple wars to the same application server. This is good, because I think it would be overkill to have a dedicated app server for each tiny gwt game. Then with Warbler, it seems I could package my RoR app to also be a war. Problem solved. Nice and Neat.

I'm really just wondering if this is the simplest way to go. I'm not super familiar with GWT, but it seems that the end product is just javascript (with perhaps many dependent assets...). Would it be simpler to extract the js from the war package, perhaps upload them to s3 or something similar, and just have my (already built and deployed) MRI RoR app serve them out like it would any other page?

I would really appreciate the insight of those with more experience than I.

Thanks a lot, and if you would like any more information about the problem, please comment and I will edit the question appropriately.

Edit:

Sorry, upon further reflection, I suppose my question boils down to this. Which is the wiser path? 1) convert my existing rails app and infrastructure to run a war package so that the games (currently in war packages) and the webapp will run neatly alongside each other. 2) extract the js and assets from the war package and have them run neatly alongside my existing MRI rails app.